# Can mybatis .NET be used directly with Oracle ODP.NET client?

Tags: c#, .net, ibatis, odp.net, mybatis

Have an existing C# .NET code base that is currently coded to directly access Oracle's ODP.NET API for database access. We're interested in doing some refactoring in this area of the application.

Our company has another Java-based code base where myBATIS is used to access Oracle db. We really like myBATIS there - so am considering myBATIS for the C# .NET application.

Yet here's the 'but': but in looking at the info on myBATIS for .NET it appears to be layered onto ADO.NET.

Would really like to have myBATIS go directly to ODP.NET for when dealing with an Oracle database. (And we'd like to have the latitude to use a very specific version of ODP.NET.)

Is that already possible to do or would we need to roll up our sleeves and code our own branch of myBATIS that layers directly onto ODP.NET (instead of ADO.NET)?

Am not a member (yet) of the myBATIS discussion groups so am asking here first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`providers` section of your `sqlMapConfig`](http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/dotnet/datamapper/ch04s03.html#id398273) should point at a [`providers.config`](http://code.google.com/p/mybatisnet/source/browse/trunk/src/MyBatis.DataMapper.SqlClient.Test/bin/Debug/providers.config) file with a provider similar to:

```
<provider 
    name="oracle10.1" 
    description="Oracle, oracle provider V10.1.0.301"
    enabled="true" 
    assemblyName="Oracle.DataAccess, Version=10.1.0.301, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" connectionClass="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection" 
    commandClass="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand" 
    parameterClass="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter" 
    parameterDbTypeClass="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType" 
    parameterDbTypeProperty="OracleDbType" 
    dataAdapterClass="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter" 
    commandBuilderClass="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommandBuilder" 
    usePositionalParameters="true" 
    useParameterPrefixInSql="true"
    useParameterPrefixInParameter="true" 
    parameterPrefix=":" 
    useDeriveParameters="false"
    allowMARS="false"    
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. I've done it before against ODP.NET and the Microsoft Oracle client, but don't remember the details.